# Proof of the Surfer Model Pagerank formula

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms, proof-writing

How do you prove this formula for the Surfer Pagerank algorithm mathematically?

```
PR(A) = (1-d) + d (PR(T1)/C(T1) + ... + PR(Tn)/C(Tn))
where:
PR(A) is the PageRank of page A,
PR(Ti) is the PageRank of pages Ti which link to page A,
C(Ti) is the number of outbound links on page Ti and
d is a damping factor which can be set between 0 and 1
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question - what do you mean by *proving a formula*? This is a formula used in the PageRank algorithm. You can discuss whether algorithm based on this formula converges. You can discuss intuition behind the formula. But if you want to prove something, you need to have some assumptions, from which you derive the formula/result/theorem/whatever.